# How to distinguish the actions tap vs. scroll on tactile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch

I'm using the folllowing code to hide a pop-up:

```
$(document).on('mouseup touchstart',function (event) {
  var container = $('#selected_thing');
  if (!container.is(event.target)                 // if the target of the click isn't the container...
  && container.has(event.target).length === 0) {  // ... nor a descendant of the container
      container.hide();
  }
});
```

The `mouseup` event for mouse click and `touchstart` event for finger tap.

How do I prevent to "tap away" the pop-up when the user's intent is not a single tap but to scroll (i.e. tap-and-drag)?

A solution that works on both recent iOS and Android browsers would be preferable.

Comment: Use `touchend` instead?

Comment: It's getting closer... :) But there isn't any event for "touchscrolling"? Because I'd like to distinguish if the intent is to "click away" the pop-up or to scroll the window and keep the pop-up visible. `touchend` keeps the pop-up visible, but of course only as long as the finger is on the screen.

Comment: You should use something like [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) if you plan on handling touch events like this. It will provide you with the `tap` event

Comment: there's a touchmove event. iOS Safari and the stock Android Internet browser handle touch events differently in scrolling. Put some console.logs() in a various touch events to get a feel for when they're fired.